# Processing Array and returning boolean value

Tags: ruby

I'm wondering, what would be the easiest way to check if all the elements of `Array` conform to certain criteria and return boolean? Is there maybe a pattern in Ruby to call method on collection and then return boolean value? Standard `Enumerable` methods return either `Array` or `nil`, so I'm not sure where to look.I've wrote an example that works using `grep`, but I feel that `if` could be skipped with more idiomatic code:

```
 def all_matched_by_regex?(regex)

     array_collection = ['test', 'test12', '12test']
     matched = array_collection.grep(regex)
     if matched.length == array_collection.length
        return true
     end
     return false
    end
```

Comment: Yes, that's it; one should be aware, though, about `all?` behaviour with empty collections (it returns true in such cases). I'd suggest checking any? as well, just reversing the pattern to check against.

Comment: That's it, yes! Not sure really how I managed to skip any/all.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try [Enumerable.all? {block}](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) ? It seems like exactly what you're looking for.

Edit:

My Ruby is a bit rusty, but here's an example of how to use it

```
  regex = /test/
=> /test/
   array_collection = ['test', 'test12', '12test']
=> ["test", "test12", "12test"]
   array_collection.all? {|obj| regex =~ obj}
=> true
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this counts as a link-only answer + a comment. Please note link-only answers are not welcome here.

Comment: @Jan there's a standard library function that does exactly what was asked. What else is there to say?

Comment: a code example would be nice. A code sample targeted at OP's situation - even better.

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
 if matched.length == array_collection.length
        return true
     end
     return false
```

with simply returning:

```
matched.length == array_collection.length
```

Like this:

```
def all_matched_by_regex?(regex)    
   array_collection = ['test', 'test12', '12test']
   matched = array_collection.grep(regex)
   matched.length == array_collection.length
end
```